# How to create a display,or similar, method with paramater?

Tags: forms, gridview, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

in my *myForm* I call in a *tableMY* a **displayMethod_fieldA**.

In *myForm* I insered a some date in a *DateEdit* and I want to make a selection in table using the entered value. If I crete a `displayMethod` whit parameter I have an error.

Look like this code I get error:

```
display myEDTField displayMethod_fieldA (date _dateFromForm)
{
 tableMY table;
 select table
 where table.item == this.item
 &&    table.dateTable == _dateFromForm;
 return table.valueFieldA;
}
```

I have an error looklike this:

> The display method has an incorrect parameter profile.

There is another way to display or set the value in my *StrinEdit* in *Grid* by method passing a parameter?

In web I saw the method `modifier` [modifierMothod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa637541.aspx) , but I need some more explanation. I don't know if this method is a right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Display methods are not designed with this feature.

> display method for a table, form, report, or report design does not
>    have any parameters. For example: display Amount amount()
>
> A display method for a form data source does require a parameter. You
>   use the
>    parameter to specify a table buffer. The type of the table buffer has
>    to match the type of the table in the form data source.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx

You can create the desired behaviour with an [edit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa595058.aspx) method (and setting the field to AllowEdit(false) or enabled(false).

Comment: Edit method will not solve it ether as it too has a specific parameter profile. What can be done is to create a datasource display method as it may have direct access to the input date.

Comment: Very vhanks all, I solved my problem, I created my _display method_ in DataSource Form.